# How to only print decimals using printf if the number of decimals is greater than 0?

Tags: c++, floating-point, printf

How would I go about using the printf() function to print a floating point number in such a way that I only print the decimal part if it is not 0? Examples:

```
1.0 -> 1
2.0 -> 2
1.5 -> 1.5
2.25 -> 2.25
```

etc.

Comment: Which format specifier are you using right now? Have you tried `%g`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("%g\n",5.0);
printf("%g\n",5.1);
```